# FMDatabaseQueue is not surviving a class init()

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

I've been trying to put together the code initializer into the `init()` function of model class I have like this:

```
 init?() {
    let docsDir =     NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let dbPath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("app.sqlite")
    let dbQueue = FMDatabaseQueue(path: dbPath)

    if dbQueue == nil {
        NSLog("%@ : %@", "Problem connecting to the db at", __FUNCTION__)
        return nil
    } else {
        NSLog("%@", "Successfully connected to the db")
    }
}
```

when I try to use `dbQueue` from another function of that class it the `dbQueue` always amount to `nil` like

```
 func anotherFunction() {
   dbQueue?.inDatabase{ db in .... }
 }
```

So when I try to initialize:

```
 let db = dbConnector()
 db.anotherFunc() // Zilch!
```

My questions is WHY this is happening and how to fix it. Please help, I'll ask Thor to bless you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using `let dbQueue` on a the class property `dbQueue` which was actually creating a local variable inside the `init()` with the same name, leaving the property uninitialized, hence the `nil`